# opencv 3.0 LatentSvmDetector class

Tags: opencv3.0

I am trying to compile code from previous version of opencv but I am getting a compiler error. The problem seems like the LatentSvmDetector is no longer available in 3.0. is this true or is there a special way to include it and compile it for opencv 3.0

thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 0):

I think V3 has renamed it to `DPMDetector`. 
See [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/dba/classcv_1_1dpm_1_1DPMDetector.html#details)